# Не работает менеджер cron на apache

Tags: apache2, cron

Всем доброго времени суток! Поставил менеджер крон https://github.com/cronkeep/cronkeep, апачу в конфигурации указал что:

```
<Directory /opt/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Захожу на ip в браузере выдает ubuntu default page. Почему то содержимое /opt/cronkeep/src не читается.

Comment: А cron при чём тут?

Answer (score -1):

Поменял в `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` строку `/var/www/` на `/opt/cronkeep/src/` и все заработало.

Comment: А после этого пробовали зайти в ваши локальные сайты, они точно работать не будут поле вашего изменения.